# Failed to install unstructured[local-inference]

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

[image]

I keep getting this error when attempting to do "pip install unstructured[local-inference]" yes I have tried doing pip install --use-pep517

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this in sequence (Make sure you are using you venv)

```
 pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

To use PEP 517, add below line in pip.config

```
 [install]
 use-pep517 = true
```

Or you can explicitly try

```
 pip install --use-pep517 package-name
```